# Can't read file content from a directory created by CREATE DIRECTORY statement

Tags: oracle

I'm using Windows 7 and I created a directory in Oracle by this statement:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY tmp AS 'D:/tmp';
```

I also created the corresponding folder D:/tmp. In folder D:/tmp, I put in a xml file 'tmp.xml'. Then, in Oracle, I run this statement to read the content of the xml file:

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('tmp', 'tmp.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF8')) xml_data
FROM dual;
```

I got the result:

XML_DATA

---

I can't see the content of the xml file. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I edited

Comment: What do you get for SELECT bfilename('tmp', 'tmp.xml') xml_data
FROM dual ?

Comment: XML_DATA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------
(BFILE)

Comment: Object names are case-sensitive, and upper-case by default, so I would expect that to error unless you've previously created a different directory as `"tmp"`. What happens if you pass `'TMP'` instead of `'tmp'`? What does `select * from all_directories` show?

Comment: I get the same result with TMP, `select * from all_directories` return SYS TMP  D:/tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly been overthinking this... the `bfile` example should have indicated what's happening, but this assumes that your original question is slightly wrong and you're actually seeing:

```
XML_DATA                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(XMLTYPE)
```

The type being shown in brackets for both queries suggests you're running this in SQL Developer; SQL*Plus hows the actual text rather than the type.

If that is the case, to show the contents you can use the [`GETSTRINGVAL` method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/t_xml.htm#i1003791):

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('TMP', 'tmp.xml'),
    nls_charset_id('UTF8')).getstringval() xml_data
FROM dual;
```

... or if the XML is more than 4000 characters the [`GETCLOBVAL` method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/t_xml.htm#i1010673).

If you're inserting the value into a table (as an `XMLTYPE` column) or doing some other manipulation on it then you don't need to convert it, you can treat it as an XMLType object.  This is just to display the value.